# How to get comments of Facebook Notes Items using several Graph API in android app?

Tags: android, facebook, asynchronous, comments

I want to show Facebook Page's Notes items with those comments and likes using Graph API.

To do that, I'm using the asyncFacebookRunner in Facebook SDK.

Steps are like this:

1. call asyncFacebookRunner.request to get Note Item with PageId

   **mAsyncRunner.request(sAPIString, new NotesRequestListener(), null);**
2. Response has come. ( I can't highlight function call. Sorry for inconvenient to find it.)

   ```
   public class NotesRequestListener implements com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener 
   {
       /**
        * Called when the request to get notes items has been completed.
        * Retrieve and parse and display the JSON stream.
        */
       @Override
       public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Log.i("My_TAG", "onComplete with response, state");
           try 
           {
               // process the response here: executed in background thread

               final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
               JSONArray arrNotesItems = json.getJSONArray("data");
               int l = (arrNotesItems != null ? arrNotesItems.length() : 0);

              // !!!!                     
              // This has another request call
              // !!!!
              final ArrayList<WordsItem> newItems = WordsItem.getWordsItems(arrNotesItems,getActivity());

               WordsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       wordsItems.clear();
                       wordsItems.addAll(newItems);
                       aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }
               }); // runOnUiThread                          
           } // try
           catch (JSONException e)
           {
               Log.i("My_TAG", "JSON Error in response");
           } // catch

   } // onComplete
            ...  other override methods ...

   } // Request Listener


   < Another Class >

   public static ArrayList<WordsItem> getWordsItems(JSONArray arrJSON, Activity activity) {
         ArrayList<WordsItem> wordsItems = new ArrayList<WordsItem>();
         int l = (arrJSON != null ? arrJSON.length() : 0);
         try {
              WordsItem newItem;           
              for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
                  JSONObject jsonObj = arrJSON.getJSONObject(i);
                  String sTitle = jsonObj.getString("subject");

                  String sNoteID = jsonObj.getString("id");
                  ... get another fields here ...
                  newItem = new WordItem(...); 

                  // !!!!                     
                  // This has request call for comments
                  // !!!!
                  ArrayList<CommentItem> arrComment = getUserComments(sNoteID);
                  wordsItems.add(newItem);
              }                
         } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return wordsItems;
      } // getWordsItems
   ```
3. call another asyncFacebookRunner.request to get comments of item(with NoteID)

   in getUserComments

   **mAsyncRunner.request(sAPIString, new CommentRequestListener(), null);**

Before getting comments(OnComplete in CommentRequestListener has not called), getWordsItems returns item array.

So I can't see the comments.

How can I wait to update UI till getting comments? 
(It's so ironic to synchronize asynchronized calls.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use facebook object which has non-asynchronous request method.
You need not implement listener method.

So, I suggest below means.

1. use mAsyncRunner.request for first request call.
2. use mFacebookRunner.request for second request call.

I hope it may help you:-)

Answer (score 0):

Using FQL - Facebook Query Language you can easily get all this information about any **[particular note info](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notes/)** 
, Also to get **[likes on that](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/)** and **[comments over it](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/)** as like examples given in the links.

Comment: I haven't use Android Facebook SDK project to get all these..but I think Quering Facbook as mentioned above you can easily get all those things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer though this is not what I want. 

I think you suggest FQL to get comments and likes. 
Using Android facebook SDK, I already can get comments & likes of Notes item.

I get note item's id first. And then get comments and likes of it.

My problem is I can't see comments & likes because app shows item contents before comments & likes have not arrived yet.

Comment: you have used AsynccTask..why dont you call second task to get comments from the onPostExecute of first task..you can update UI as per you get data in task's onPostExecute using runOnUiThread

Comment: hmm... I called second task on OnCompleted instead of onPostExecute. I'll try chaging my code according to your suggestion. Let it may work. Thx :-)

Comment: look you have 2 asynctask...call first..in First's onPostExecute() you get note info ..regarding that if you want to update ui do it using runOnUiThread..then from there call second Task..and in that onPostExecute do UI change..It will be a lot simpler if you go step by step

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I using com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner for asynchronous request. Its RequestListener has onComplete, not onPostExecute. This makes differences??

Comment: no but after authenticating..you must be haveing another thread/asynctask to load page detail and one for loading comments..i am talking about them

Comment: A little confusing;) In my above codes, second asynctask is called from the first one's onComplete. First onComplete method call getWordsItem method which has second asynctask call. My problem is that first asynctask is done before second response yet to come. I want the first asynctask's termination follows the second one.